# Load Data in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, load

I am developing a GUI where I want the input in text or excel format from user. When he will click on "Upload File" button from my GUI, the file browser will open and he will select the text file. Once he clicks open the file should be in workspace so my next code will take the value give results.

What I did is: Have this code under the push button

```
[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt')
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename)
data = load(loaddata)
A = data(:,1)
B = data(:,2)
C = data(:,3)
D = data(:,4)
handles.input1 = A;
handles.input2 = B;
handles.input3 = C;
handles.input4 = D;
```

Now when the Browser opens, I can select .txt file which is having 4 columns and 2000 rows of data. But when I go back to workspace, I can't see anything in workspace but all values from 2nd column in command window!

Comment: if you want something from within the GUI to be shown in workspace, you have to use `assignin('base', 'you_choose_name_for_var_in_workspace', var_name_in_GUI)`, where `var_name_in_GUI` actually should be your `handles.???`. See more here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?refresh=true) and the associated [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html?searchHighlight=getappdata) to store application-defined data and retrieve  it from elsewhere, for example from a GUI or the base workspace.

In your case, you could store `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` in the base workspace so they would be available from your other scripts. You can also store the `handles` structure if you want.

As an example, your code in the GUI could look like this:

```
[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt')
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename)
data = load(loaddata)

%// Store in the base workspace (i.e. the "0")
setappdata(0,'AllData',data);
```

Note that you could write anything you want as a name, as long as you retrieve the variable with the same name using `getappdata`. Here I used `AllData` but you could leave that as `data` just as well.

Therefore, in the other script you are running, use `getappdata` like so:

```
DataInScript = getappdata(0,'AllData');

    A = AllData(:,1)
    B = AllData(:,2)
    C = AllData(:,3)
    D = AllData(:,4)
```

So now, depending on whether you already assigned A, B, C and D you can access your data directly from `AllData`.